# How to get Camera Pose from Aruco Pose in Unity?

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

I have the transform from an Aruco Marker and i would like to get the Camera pose using that information.
How can i update the camera pose using only the transform from an Aruco marker.

I would like to make this estimation in unity but i am not sure how to.

Comment: with opencv you can use solvePnp function to get object pose relative to camera. To get camera pose relative to object, use the inverse result. Maybe you'll have to transform between different coordinate systems in Unity and openCV

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/flankechen/ArUco_Unity

I used to make a plungin for Unity using Aruco for AR. The model view matrix from Aruco is enough for the camera pose. In the c# code, I get the left handed tranform in native Aruco, for opengl, transform it to right handed for Unity, inverse and get the position and rotation to set the Unity camera. check https://github.com/flankechen/ArUco_Unity/blob/master/RenderingPluginExample52_ArUco_unity/UnityProject/Assets/UseRenderingPlugin.cs for detail.
The "cool" part is tranfrom from left handed to right haned system. not all the "google code" works.

```
//reform a left handed system transform matrix from right handed
public static Matrix4x4 LHMatrixFromRHMatrix(Matrix4x4 rhm)
{
    Matrix4x4 lhm = new Matrix4x4();;
    
    // Column 0.
    lhm[0, 0] =  rhm[0, 0];
    lhm[1, 0] =  rhm[1, 0];
    lhm[2, 0] = -rhm[2, 0];
    lhm[3, 0] =  rhm[3, 0];
    
    // Column 1.
    lhm[0, 1] =  rhm[0, 1];
    lhm[1, 1] =  rhm[1, 1];
    lhm[2, 1] = -rhm[2, 1];
    lhm[3, 1] =  rhm[3, 1];
    
    // Column 2.
    lhm[0, 2] = -rhm[0, 2];
    lhm[1, 2] = -rhm[1, 2];
    lhm[2, 2] =  rhm[2, 2];
    lhm[3, 2] = -rhm[3, 2];
    
    // Column 3.
    lhm[0, 3] =  rhm[0, 3];
    lhm[1, 3] =  rhm[1, 3];
    lhm[2, 3] = -rhm[2, 3];
    lhm[3, 3] =  rhm[3, 3];
    
    return lhm;
}
```